# Wired network connection fails after return from sleep in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, suspend

I just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04. Everything worked fine with 18.04, but after the upgrade every time the PC returns from sleep the wired network connection is gone. I cannot see the connection on the top bar and when looking at the network setup area it is also showing like the hardware is missing. The only way I have found to bring the connection back is to do a restart which works, but is a pain. Any ideas why the upgrade caused this problem and how to fix it short of going back to 18.04?

I have also tried a manual shutdown of the network using..

sudo nmcli networking off
sudo nmcli networking on

This created exactly the same symptoms. The shutdown worked, but the network did not restart using the networking on command. I do have a VPN, but the problem is the same if the VPN is active or not.

Thanks

PS. Gave up waiting for a response and solved the problem by installing a PCI-E ethernet card (A$15). This second ethernet port does not suffer the same issue of failing to return after putting the PC to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem after upgrading to 21.04, this desktop has wifi as well which means I can limp along for now but the wired lan comes up DISABLED after  resuming from sleep according to lspci -C network.

A diff of the output shows missing attributes after resume but I cant find a reason why this happens or way to turn it back on without a reboot.

Before reboot
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
logical name: enp4s0
version: 10
serial: b8:85:84:b6:43:a7
size: 1Gbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=5.11.0-22-generic duplex=full ip=192.168.86.224 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
resources: irq:19 memory:ec500000-ec53ffff ioport:d000(size=128)

After Reboot
*-network **DISABLED**
description: Ethernet interface
product: Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
logical name: enp4s0
version: 10
serial: b8:85:84:b6:43:a7
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 multicast=yes
resources: irq:19 memory:ec500000-ec53ffff ioport:d000(size=128)

Comment: As much as I have issues with Windows and their policies the driver support seems to be way ahead of Linux. It would appear to be pot luck when you install Ubuntu how well stuff will work and things can break by upgrading to a newer version of Ubuntu. My experience with two different machines has been reliable systems, but with odd behaviors when returning from sleep on both machines. Not a deal breaker, just annoying. The simple fix is do not use sleep and if you need to save power turn off the monitor or shutdown.